# Washer malfunction/reset?

Tags: washing-machine

Hello:I have a Whirlpool Thin Twin Mod # LTE5243DQA,it's about 5-7 year's old.  The washer suddenly stopped while in the rinse cycle with the
tub full of water. I "played" with the Load Size control and used the Reset, which for some reason started the washer.  Is this a sign of further problems, what course of action should I take to prevent a re-occurance?

Comment: I'm assuming there is a question in here somewhere but I just can't find it..

Comment: I was hoping from my description - that someone might be able to let me know what happened,

Comment: My mistake-the following was left out:  Is this a sign of further/future problems - what steps/actions should I take for preventing a re-occurance ?  Thank you.

Comment: Big guess but it could have been power problems that caused the washer to stop , a power bump this time of year is normal where I live so unless it regularly starts happening I agree with @jack

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a little premature to try and diagnose a problem that at the time doesn't exist. There are a few micro switches, like the one in the washer door, that if not completely closed can stop the machine. Maybe a problem with the gear cam that will stop the machine at the same place each time. Is the Reset button a system reset or a load size reset? If a system reset, you might have corrected the problem like a reboot on a computer... 
Monitor the operation of the machine and try to get some more information. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - it is a Load Size Reset - I used it twice and the machine only operated while holding the control in the Reset position.  However, on the third try with the Reset the washer went back to normal operation.  I did try pushing down on the lid switch but nothing happened.